# How to avoid repeated builds and speed up builds using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently working on adding CMake support to a library that currently uses waf as its build system. The code I have for CMake is excruciatingly slow compared to the existing build system with waf, and I believe it is because of the following reason.

The part of my CMake code that adds libraries and executables looks something like this

```
# USE_PACKAGES is a variable with loaded libraries like Boost::serialization
add_library(library_a SHARED)
target_sources(library_a PUBLIC ${LIBRARY_A_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(library_a PRIVATE ${USE_PACKAGES})

add_library(library_b SHARED)
target_sources(library_b PUBLIC ${LIBRARY_B_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(library_b PRIVATE ${USE_PACKAGES} library_a)

add_executable(executable)
target_sources(executable PUBLIC ${EXECUTABLE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(executable PRIVATE ${USE_PACKAGES} library_a library_b)
```

What I can see is that when I run `make && make install` after the makefile has been generated, make first builds library_a, then in order to build library_b, it builds both library_b and library_a, and then to build the executable, it builds executable, library_b, and library_a.

So for example if LIBRARY_A_SOURCE had a file called library_a/library_a_foo.cxx, and similarly for library_b with bar.cxx, at the stage where make is building library_b, the log first shows `Building CXX Object library_b/library_b_bar.cxx`, and then it also shows `Building CXX Object library_a/library_a_foo.cxx`, even though `foo.cxx` was already built when library_a was being built.

I believe this is the source of why make is being slow. Is there a way to build every library only once?

I tried playing with the visibility a bit, but changing the PRIVATE to PUBLIC does not seem to change this behaviour.

Edit - I should have been clearer, I am talking about the stage where I run `make && make install`. Added more context, plus, fixed typos.

Comment: CMake (or, more correct, a **build tool** for which a project is configured) doesn't rebuild a library if its sources and headers aren't changed. If you observe unnecessary rebuilding and ask us to help with it, then you need to provide **more details** about your case. Preferably, [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I apologise for the confusion, I am a beginner at CMake so I am still learning what things mean. I meant that the build tool is rebuilding things when I run `make && make install`. I will add more clarification as two what I mean by "make rebuilds a library" to the body of the question

Comment: Rebuilding the source is caused by using PUBLIC keyword in `target_sources` call. Instead, use PRIVATE keyword.

Comment: Do you have a reason to do `add_library(...)` followed by `target_sources(...)` instead  of directly doing `add_library(library_a SHARED ${LIBRARY_A_SOURCES})`? The latter practice is much more common.